# How to prevent someone from proxying your Websites

Tags: proxy, attack-prevention, websites

So i think someone is mirroring my site with a proxy and hides behind cloudflare (cloudflare already notified and google also) so i cant find out the real ip of the server to block it.

Is there anyway to detect if your website is opening in a other domain and block it or redirect it?

maybe some javascript hostname lookup and then redirect? or is there a better solution?

Im using Cyberpanel with Openlitespeed, Configsever Firewall, Modesecurity and as CMS Wordpress latest version and Cloudflare for DNS

Edit:
**Solution for people who are in the same situation**

Go to the "attacker" website and add some characters at the end of the url like
domain.com/?upuuukgkhlgkhlgkh
and then check your access log for these characters and make sure if you are on cloudflare that you configured your server to show the real ips in the access log
copy the ip from the logs double check on utrace.com that the ip is not from cloudflare or any other cdn and block it on cloudflare and/or your server

in my case they used different ips so make sure to check the other domain again and refresh it a couple times if your site still shows up do the same procedure again till all ips are blocked.

note: this doesnt prevent them from doing it on another vps again but for now i have no permanent solution for that. if i find one i will update it

Comment: Is your site being displayed in a frame/iframe?  If so, you can use javascript to break out.

Comment: Are you saying that there is a rogue proxy server that is mirroring your site by somehow making requests through cloudflare to your web server?  If so, how do you know this?

Comment: unfortunetly it's not. i tried to block iframe via javascript just to make sure..wasnt working

Comment: @mti they did it on 2 different domains one was showing real server ip other sits behind cloudflare. i blocked the ip of the real one but its still showing my site. then i uploaded a php fiel to my server to resolve the remote ip of the server..then i visited the file on the other domain and it shows just cloudflare ips. they host images, css and js o their own domain but replaced affiliate links and other external links with their own links and even placed ads on it.

Comment: and its not copied or some kind of rss feed grabbing because its showing my actual site with live updates. when i upload any file to the server and open it on their domain i can access it

Comment: I'm not sure how a server that is not on cloudflare's network can make an HTTP(S) request to another server that is not on cloudflare's network, through cloudflare.  That is not how cloudflare works.  The more likely scenario is that someone is abusing cloudflare's service, by using it the way it is intended to be used (as a WAF) but for your site.  What does a DNS lookup of the FQDN show?

Comment: when i hostname --fqdn it shows localhost as name..shouldnt it show the server name instead?

Comment: Try doing `nslookup hostname.domain.tld` where hostname.domain.tld is the site that is mirroring your site.  It should return an IP address.  Then, do a whois or a PTR lookup on that IP address, and see if it shows that it is on cloudflare's network.  If so, then that explains it.

Comment: for one domain it shows cloudflare ips for the other domain it shows the real ip to some russian hosting. i already blocked the ip in cloudflare and on server firewall but the site still shows up. i had this happen last year also some security guy was helping me out by adding characters the url that dont exist on my end to see later the ips in access log..they used about 5 different ips..after i blocked the ips their site stopped working.. i thought its done but they do it again now with other domains but this time the access log version is not wokring its not showing up

Comment: ok just saw that the access log was not correctly logging..i fixed it now it is working....i add some characters like ?nfgjfngrrrg on their domain and then check my access logs..i see it and the ip is from cloudflare

Comment: As for cloudflare - I would think if you report this to them, with all of the details (i.e. the FQDN where this is happening, the IP on their network that this FQDN points to, your logs, etc), they will take down the site.  As for the Russian site, this might be harder if they are using multiple IP's.  If they are in a range, you can try blocking the whole range.  They may also be caching, in which case, blocking them won't help.

Comment: i already did it waiting for a reply from cloudflare but this is not solving the problem in the future they can just set it up again under different domains. is there no way of preventing it on my end?

Comment: can you explain what these russians did?  Can they setup cloudflare to mirror/cache a site they don't own??  Wouldn't they need the private key for https?

Comment: so there is 2 different domains doing it but i think its both the same person..the russian domain via utrace resolves to a russian hosting company but  it seems they still use cloudflare to "proxy" the site because in the access log i see cloudflare ips from their server. i dont even know if you can call it proxy im a noob to that..thats what i believe after google for some days to find a way to prevent it. we dont use our own certificate..we use the free one inlcuding in cloudflare.

Comment: I think "reverse proxy" is what it is, but I've never used Cloudflare and have always avoided using any type of CDN.  Sorta strange that they claim to be improving "privacy" when they have your private key and are a middle man for all traffic.  (and apparently redirecting caches to another server??)

Comment: ok there was a misconfiguration on my end it showed cloudflare ips instead of real ips in the access log. i configured it before but it wasnt working for some reason. so their are just hiding their domain behind cloudflare but while access log now shows real ips i see the real ips of their servers they are using mainly Netherland Hosts. I identified 8 different ips and blocked them with iptables and cloudflare. now their domains showing access denied

Comment: can someone with knowledge of Cloudflare explain what happened here?  If you use Cloudflare's DNS, does that mean they have to reverse proxy?  And how does another domain name get routed to the same cache?  (Or am I completely misunderstanding this?)

Comment: they created another domain with different host..i need to find a better solution for this.. manually resolving their server ips and block it consumes a lot of time

Comment: You cannot prevent it. Legal action might be a viable avenue if the attacker is in a "good" jurisdiction. For that you will need to work with law enforcement.

Answer (score 1):

## Your question is a bit confusing

A mirror is usually a copy of the entire site, so I'm guessing you mean forwarding/proxying and not mirroring.

## Forwarding

You could save the **HTTP request header** data for each incoming connection.

There are several fields there which could give you useful information.

- Examine the *value* of the field named **Forwarded**.
- The fields named **X-Forwarded-**... are also worth a peek.

**Wikipedia article with more info:**
[HTTP header fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

## HTTPS & Certificates

Make sure you use HTTPS instead of plain old HTTP.

Proxy servers can't forward HTTPS traffic transparently without installing a certificate on each client.

If you make sure each page redirects to itself with an absolute FQDN path the first time a NEW client connects, you will make unwanted redirection a real headache...

Checking link referrals etc. will let you inspect traffic too.

Comment: wrt 'Proxy servers can't forward HTTPS traffic transparently without installing a certificate on each client' - I think the OP is saying that the proxy sites are using a different domain than his site's domain.  So, the proxy sites don't need to install OP's certificate (and private key).

Comment: That's why he should have pages forward the request to themselves with an absolute path including FQDN the fist time a new unique client connects.